# What does "shovel it thin" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), columnist J.J. Hunsecker warns Senator Harvey Walker
about agent:

> J.J. Hunsecker: This man is not for you, Harvey...and you shouldn't be
> seen in public with him. Because that's another part of a press
> agent's life: They dig up scandal about prominent people... and **shovel
> it thin** among columnists who give them space.

What does "shovel it thin" mean?

Comment: *Shovel* is a verb and the word *it* means scandal.  The verb is used in a metaphoric fashion meaning *spread around (like you would manure).*

Comment: What about **thin** word?

Comment: **Thinly** (in a thin layer).

Comment: @Lambie That's answer-worthy

Comment: @gotube I'll let EllieK get it. :)

Comment: @Lambie - My best effort would be to copy and paste what you've said which doesn't seem quite right.  You took the extra effort to illustrate the metaphor.   I think this is your answer.   :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ellie K

> Shovel is a verb and the word it means is scandal. The verb is used in a
> metaphoric fashion meaning spread around (like you would manure).

Me:

> Yes, Ellie is right. What a native speaker would understand is this:
> They dig up shit that creates a scandal for prominent people. There is
> also the slang: to shovel shit. So the shit is being shoveled (passed)
> onto columnists in small doses.